# How to declare Enum and Custom classes in numba jitclass spec?

Tags: python, numba

I am trying out numba (v0.56.4), I have a python enum Color, I want to declare it in @jitclass spec for class Paint. Can you please let me know the right way to declare it?

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 3

spec = [('name': types. String), ('color': Color)]

@jitclass(spec)
class Paint:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self. Color = color
```

When I directly give Enum Color in spec, I am getting error TypeError:

> spec values should be Numba type instances, got <enum 'Color'>

If I try to give int32 or int64 instead of enum Color, then I get error:

```
('color', types.int64) # gives error
```

> Cannot cast Enum(Color) to int64.

If I create a wrapper class for Color with @jitclass on ColorWrapper, I am getting error

> TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got <class
> 'numba.experimental.jitclass.base.ColorWrapper'>

As per numba documentation I can use enum in njit functions but I could not find way to declare Enum types and custom classes with @jitclass for another class's @jitclass spec

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `Color` a subclass of `enum.IntEnum` (an `Enum` type with a mixin-type of `int`) instead so that it can be converted to `int64`:

```
class Color(IntEnum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 3

spec = [('name', string), ('color', int64)]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/SparseEminentFlashdrives